# Open URLs in Native FB App

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I've been reading on deep linking and App Links and such.

I was just wondering if it was possible on Android to simply share a URL of a Facebook Profile or Album on say WhatsApp or Telegram and get it to open in the native FB app instead of in the browser.

If not possible, why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Sean, the reason why this is not possible is because Facebook does not implement AppLinks. This means, there's no metadata on someone's profile URL so when shared, it is automatically handled by the Facebook Native Application.